# Does Scikit-Learn's OneHotEncoder make all Columns Categorical?

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, pipelines

I've been using Scikit-Learn's `OneHotEncoder` to turn categorical data into binary columns, however, it seems that fitting `OneHotEncoder` to a dataset with numerical and categorical variables causes it to make binary columns for the numerical data too.

I've tried searching the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) for an explicit answer, but I can't find one. Does `OneHotEncoder` automatically avoid encoding numerical columns? If not, how can I make a pipeline with it without splitting and re-joining the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(My basic answer, post a more informed one and I'll accept it.)

Examples from this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/categorical-encoding-using-label-encoding-and-one-hot-encoder-911ef77fb5bd) show that the `OneHotEncoder` will encode for every unique value in a column.

You can check what's being encoded by using the `OneHotEncoder().categories_` attribute. This attribute will give you a series of arrays that include all the unique values of each column that have been encoded for. If you feed numerical values into the `OneHotEncoder` you'll notice that these arrays contain every unique numerical value as a category.

To avoid this, you should pre-select your categorical columns and feed those to the `OneHotEncoder`. See the following [SciKit-Learn Tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html), and the reference for [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer) to see how this can be included in a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn's OneHotEncoder will encode all variables in the dataframe by default.

If you want to encode just a subset, you need to wrap the OneHotEncoder with the [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html).

Alternatively, you can use Feature-engine's OneHotEncoder which encodes only variables of type object or categorical by default, leaving the numerical variables the way they are.

See for example this code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
from feature_engine.encoding import OneHotEncoder
X = pd.DataFrame(dict(x1 = [1,2,3,4], x2 = ["a", "a", "b", "c"]))
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
ohe.fit(X)
ohe.transform(X)
```

The result of that transformation is the following dataframe, where the numerical variable remains unchanged and the categorical one was one hot encoded:

```
   x1  x2_a  x2_b  x2_c
0   1     1     0     0
1   2     1     0     0
2   3     0     1     0
3   4     0     0     1
```

I leave a link to Feature-engine's [OneHotEncoder](https://feature-engine.trainindata.com/en/latest/api_doc/encoding/OneHotEncoder.html#feature_engine.encoding.OneHotEncoder) for more details.

Comment: I found `pandas.get_dummies` to be most useful in the end: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html